# Tasker app creation: is it possible to let user select the apps for launch app context

Tags: tasker

Well, as the question states, while creating a tasker profile, if the launch app context is used, a list of apps has to be chosen. I was wondering if I make an app using this profile, is it possible to let the user edit this list? So that he may add or remove some apps from the default list?

This is my first question in this site. Greetings, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a scene with a small menu of apps, set to open the app when the user taps it's icon.

One issue: Errors might arise if you have Tasker try to open an app that the user does not have installed. One way around this would be to use the shell command 'pm list packages' and (somehow) resolve the name of the chosen app to the package name, or the reverse and use this to populate the displayed list.